# iOS ,UiSplitViewController Doesn't run with AppDelegate

Tags: ipad, uistoryboard, appdelegate, uiwindow, uisplitview

i create one Main-iPad.Storyboard with Split View Controller  Windows and App Delegate

here are my app Delegate.h

```
   IBOutlet UISplitViewController * rootcontroler;
   UIWindow *window;
```

here are my app Delegate.m

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    


    UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-iPad" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *initviewcontroller = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window setRootViewController:initviewcontroller];



}
```

and i added in Target-> General -> Main InterFace = Main-iPad

but when i run the app i received the black screen

Comment: Select your `UISplitViewController` in your StoryBoard, in the Attribute inspector check if "Is Initial View Controller" is checked.

Comment: Do you have a details view linked to your `UISplitViewController`in your Storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to load storyboard with `UISplitViewController` initial vc from the code, remove respective key from target's **Info.plist** and add this code to the `AppDelegate.m`

```
// loading initial vc the way many folks around do
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UIViewController *vc =[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = vc;

// set up split vc
self.splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
self.splitViewController.delegate = self;
self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;
self.splitViewController.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 0.5;
// do any other split vc customization if needed

// this is an important part: call this _after_ split vc set up, otherwise you'd get wrong collapsed vc presented by split vc
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

also, [the gist](https://gist.github.com/evgeniyd/70710fad9455d6e2e34e)